# Firebase Function fails connecting to Firestore using Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a Firebase Function using the Admin SDK that should retrieve data from Firestore (function triggered upon RealTime DB insert event).

It looks as if the Relatime DB is kicking in fine, but when I added the Firestore code, it is failing on the Firestore connection with the following error on deployment:

```
    Error: Missing expected firebase config value databaseURL, config is actually{"firebase":{"projectId":"simplify-poc","databaseURL":"https://simplify-poc-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com","storageBucket":"simplify-poc.appspot.com","locationId":"us-central"}}
     If you are unit testing, please set process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG
```

This is my function code, what am I missing?

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

async function getHelperToken(helperId) {
  //Get token from Firestore
  const tokensRef = db.collection("tokens");
  const helper_token = await tokensRef
    .where("user", "==", helperId)
    .get("device_token");
  return helper_token;
}

//DB triggered function - upon writing a child in the HelpersInvitations reference
exports.sendHelperInvitation = functions.database
  .ref("/HelpersInvitations/{helper_invitation_id}")
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const studentId = snapshot.val().studentId;
    const studentName = snapshot.val().studentName;
    const helperId = snapshot.val().helperId;
    const title = snapshot.val().title;
    const body = snapshot.val().body;

    //Get the helper token by Id
    const helper_token = getHelperToken(helperId);
    //Notification payload
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: title,
        body: body,
        icon: "default",
        click_action: "com.skillblaster.app.helperinvitationnotification",
      },
    };

  //    //Send the notification
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(helper_token, payload);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Was probably a bug with Firebase tools.
I upgraded Firebase tools from 9.16.2 to 9.16.5 and problem gone!

To upgrade:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the app like this worked for me.

```js
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Did not make any difference on my end.

Comment: Make sure your service account is setup on GCP

Comment: should I explicitly configur GCP? FB Console isn't enough? I can write to my project data from a mobile-client program just fine.